# How do I write a Google Sheets Query where I can use the user's input (cell reference) to determine the

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

The goal of this sheet I am working on is for someone to select the items they want on a report (I created a dropdown with data validation), and based on the options the user select, THIS will be the Column letter to use in my Query.

For example, my query works perfectly when I do:

`=QUERY('Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!A:AG, "select A WHERE C='Yes'")`

However, the "C = 'Yes' part is where I'm struggling. I don't want the user to have to edit my formula. I want to use the column number from what they selected.

I created the following formula to pull in the letter of the answer, based on the data tables:
`=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B6,'Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!$1:$1,0),4),"1","")`

This works great all on its own, but when I try to do something like this, it doesn't work:

`=QUERY('Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!A:AG, "select A WHERE '"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B6,'Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!$1:$1,0),4),"1","")&"' = 'Yes'")`

Basically, this works:
`=QUERY('Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!A:AG, "select A WHERE C='Yes'")`

But the one above doesn't.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks that the problem is that your formula is enclosing the columns letters between `'`, in other words, remove the first `'` after `WHERE` and the one before `=`:

```
=QUERY('Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!A:AG, "select A WHERE '"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B6,'Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!$1:$1,0),4),"1","")&"' = 'Yes'")
                                                                         ^                                                                                                 ^
                                                                         |                                                                                                 |
                                                                         |                                                                                                 |
```

The resulting formula is:

`=QUERY('Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!A:AG, "select A WHERE "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(B6,'Common Standard Reports & Fields Included'!$1:$1,0),4),"1","")&" = 'Yes'")`

Comment: Ruben, THANK YOU so much! I was reading online about the syntax for this, and so many places I was reading showed both a ‘ and a “ but I tried what you said and it worked!!!! You’re my hero!

Comment: @DavidHammond Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)